# Cobian backup error "The system cannot find the path specified" but the path does exist

Tags: backup, logging

I have started using cobian backup. Here is the log from my last backup. It should have backed up 20GB but only did 5GB.

Cobian backup error "The system cannot find the path specified" but the path does exist.

```
2014-07-24 11:35 ** Backing up the task "jlDocuments" **
2014-07-24 11:35 Counting the files for the task "jlDocuments"...
2014-07-24 11:35 Starting the Volume Shadow Copy snapshot for the drives: C:\
2014-07-24 11:35 The Volume Shadow Copy snapshot set has been created successfully
2014-07-24 11:35 Creating the destination directory "E:\Documents 2014-07-24 11;35;10 (Differential)"
2014-07-24 11:35 The destination directory "E:\Documents 2014-07-24 11;35;10 (Differential)"  has been successfully created
2014-07-24 11:35 Backing up the directory "GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy12\Users\jl\Documents"
ERR 2014-07-24 11:35 Couldn't copy the file "GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy12\Users\jl\Documents\backupEvernote\Evernote 2014-07-24 11;23;34 (Full)\Atlas\js\libs\json2.js.enz": The system cannot find the file specified
ERR 2014-07-24 11:35 Couldn't copy the file "GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy12\Users\jl\Documents\backupEvernote\Evernote 2014-07-24 11;23;34 (Full)\Atlas\js\libs\jsonrpc.js.enz": The system cannot find the file specified
```

and so on, the same error different files

```
ERR 2014-07-24 11:38 Couldn't create the directory "E:\Documents 2014-07-24 11;35;10 (Differential)\Copy\macnörderi\web\email - 5 processa inboxen.screenflow": The system cannot find the path specified
```

and so on

```
ERR 2014-07-24 11:38 Couldn't create the directory "E:\Documents 2014-07-24 11;35;10 (Differential)\Copy\Skola": The system cannot find the path specified
```

until the end where it gave me a summary

```
2014-07-24 11:38 Deleting the Volume Shadow Copy snapshot "bf7509e1-788c-4f0a-b547-3111b6c3e9b2"
2014-07-24 11:38 The Volume Shadow Copy snapshot set has been successfully deleted
2014-07-24 11:38 Total backup time for "jlDocuments": 0 hours, 3 minutes, 15 seconds
2014-07-24 11:38 ** Backup done for the task "jlDocuments". Errors: 580. Processed files: 4066. Backed up files: 605. Total size: 5,13 GB **
2014-07-24 11:38 -- 
2014-07-24 11:38 The system can now enter sleep mode
2014-07-24 11:38 Total backup time: 0 hours, 3 minutes, 19 seconds
2014-07-24 11:38 *** Backup done.  Errors: 580.  Processed files: 4066. Backed up files: 605. Total size: 5,13 GB ***
2014-07-24 11:38 --
```

What should I do? The files are there for sure.

If someone has a better free program feel free to tell me.

Comment: It seems like a privilege security setting for the application to run as administrator to access user protected documents may do it or some other similar means . Windows often gives this message for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In Cobain Backup I have found on occasion that I need to recreate the backup options in order for it to function correctly. Try adding these folders manually instead of a top tier folder if the above fails.

Is this an automated or manual backup that kicks off? 
Do you have folder permissions that may limit these files from being copied?  To find out right click the folder and click properties. Then select security. Check that the current user has read/write permissions for the specified folder.